# Multiple public RSA keys on server, sharing same SSH login details

Tags: ssh, rsa

At my company we use SSH to access a server in order to deploy projects through GIT. We share the same SSH login details to access the server. When I log in I always get prompted to enter the pass-phrase for my colleagues RSA key:

```
Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/colleagues_rsa':
```

I thought by creating my own RSA key (without a pass-phrase) and linking it to the company on-line git repository (We use bitbucket) that this would bypass this issue. However, I am still prompted to enter my colleagues pass-phrase each time I use `git pull`.

As a note, I use `git@bibucket.org`... not `https`... so this shouldn't be the issue. This also only affects this server.

The only time I personally got this error was when I created an RSA key with a pass-phrase. Is this the issue here or am I missing something to do with RSA authentication on a per user basis?

Comment: So it's asking for a passphrase to your colleagues key when you do a git pull? Can you paste the command and message? Also, is your new key in your agent? "ssh-agent -l" should show that.

Comment: @Peter `ssh-agent -l` gives unknown option. I have just copied my private key which I generated on the server `root/.ssh/mykey` to my own local machine `/home/me/.ssh/mykey` and added it using `ssh-add /home/me/.ssh/mykey`. Tried again and still get prompted for my colleagues RSA key...

Comment: Sorry, that should have been "ssh-add -l" (you can forget about that now). I don't use bitbucket but it sounds like you might need to further configure something in there if it's only prompting you for one key.